# Missing parameter error when submitting a form with two request params

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Below is code from a controller that I'm aiming to make sure it's receiving two input parameters (name and code) from a front-end interface.

It's a page that takes two parameters within a submit form, "name" and "code".

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String transfer(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name,
                         @RequestParam(name = "code") String code,
                         Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        try {
            User userToBeTransferred = usersRepository.findByName(name);
            userToBeTransferred.setTransferred(true);

            Region regionOfTransference = regionsRepository.findByCode(code);
            regionOfTransference.setPopulationNumber(regionOfTransference.getPopulationNumber() + 1);

            userToBeTransferred.setRegion(regionOfTransference);

            usersRepository.save(userToBeTransferred);
            regionsRepository.save(regionOfTransference);

            return "redirect:/section/users/new";
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return "htmlPageOne";
        }
    }
```

The front-page form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/section/users/new" th:object="${user}">

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-form-label">User name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:field="*{name}" name="name"/></div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="code" class="col-form-label">Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" th:field="*{region.code}" name="code"/></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-6 ">Save</button>
        </form>
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following error after I click to submit the form :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'code' is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'code' is not present
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the requestparams correctly, so maybe it's got something to do with this? I don't know, I've been stuck on this for a few hours now, so would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `th:field="*{region.code}"` overrides your `name` attribute into `name="region.code"`. You can tell by inspecting the rendered `<input>` element using dev tools of your browser.

You can change following

```
th:field="*{region.code}"
```

...into:

```
th:value="${user.region.code}"
```